# Given two unit vectors u and v such that ||u+v||=3/2, find ||u-v||

Tags: vectors

Given two unit vectors u and v such that ||u+v||=3/2, find ||u-v||

I am not sure how to go about this problem, so any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I expect that the point of this exercise is for you to use or discover the _parallelogram identity_.

Comment: $\|u+v\|^2\pm \|u-v\|^2=$?. BTW \|x\| comes out as $\|x\|$ which is easier to read than $||x||$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that $u$ and $v$ are both *unit* vectors, i.e. $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$, we can then state that:

$\begin{eqnarray}\|u+v\|^2 & = & (u+v) \cdot (u+v) \\
& = & u \cdot u + v \cdot v + 2(u \cdot v) \\
& = & \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2(u \cdot v) \\
\left (\frac{3}{2} \right )^2 & = & 1 + 1 + 2(u \cdot v) \\
\therefore u \cdot v & = & \frac{1}{8}\end{eqnarray}$

Then, by applying similar reasoning, you can derive the value of $\|u-v\|$.